# Getting a list of `PackageDescriptions` from the local database

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is there anyway, presumably using the [`Cabal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal) package, to get a list of [`PackageDesciption`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-2.0.0.2/docs/Distribution-PackageDescription.html#t:PackageDescription)s in the current local database?

Comment: Is there anything unclear in my answer, or do you need a "haskell" solution instead of shell cruft

Comment: I'd prefer a Haskell solution other than shell cruft. But the shell cruft helps, I'll dig into "ghc-pkg"s source and see how it does it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a "built-in"-way of doing this, but I've used this

```
ghc-pkg list | grep -v "\(^/\|^$\|(\)" | xargs cabal info | grep "\(^\*\|License\)"
```

to extract "License" info for all installed packages.

1. If you use `stack` or `cabal-sandbox` - the first command needs to be replaced by either `stack exec -- ghc-pkg list` or `cabal sandbox hc-pkg list`.
2. the (first) regex removes the path-lines like `/opt/ghc/8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/package.conf.d`, empty lines and lines starting with `(` - somehow the colored lines produced by `ghc-pkg` like `ghc-8.0.2` end up with starting `(` in my terminal when grepping.
3. "map cabal info over all packages"
4. [optional] extracting the package information for the package itself (starting with `*` and the `License` field.

I hope this is what you were looking for. Another way, I think, would be writing a haskell program and use `Cabal` as a library.